# Unable to connect two devices via Ethernet because the default gateway for connection keeps getting set as 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, ethernet

I am trying to connect my PlayStation 2 with my Windows 10 laptop into a network using an Ethernet cable between the two. My laptop is connected to the internet via Wi-Fi hotspot on my Android phone and I have set that connection to be shared with other networks in the settings for my PC's Wi-Fi adapter. My end goal is setting up a SMB share between the PS2 and the laptop.

When I connected my PS2 to my laptop with an Ethernet cable, the Ethernet network was without internet connection. I went into cmd.exe and ran "ipconfig /all" to see that two addresses are displayed as the Ethernet connection's default gateway: 0.0.0.0, and below it the address that I have actually wanted to set as the default gateway (192.168.137.1).

I can run "route delete 0.0.0.0" in cmd.exe and when I do that, the Network and Sharing Center in the Control Panel shows the Wi-Fi and Ethernet connections finally sharing a network, which is what I am trying to achieve, but the moment I run "route delete 0.0.0.0" my laptop gets disconnected from the Wi-Fi hotspot so the fact that the connections are sharing a network now becomes irrelevant because they don't have access to the internet. When I reconnect the laptop to the Wi-Fi hotspot, the Wi-Fi connection immediately stops sharing the network with the Ethernet connection because the "0.0.0.0" default gateway immediately gets generated again for that connection.

How do I connect my devices into a functional Ethernet network? How do I avoid "0.0.0.0" being set as the default gateway for the connection and thus blocking network sharing?

Comment: Did you at all enable Sharing for the WiFi connection? That's the way to share a WiFi connection https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/share-internet-connection-windows-ethernet-wi-fi

Comment: @YisroelTech Yes, I have done absolutely everything as that tutorial suggests, but it's as if something external is blocking the Wi-Fi from actually being shared. No matter what I do, I get "no internet connection" in the Ethernet network

Comment: Have you tried manually setting up the IP and subnet for the two devices Ethernet?